# How to allow lookup field in VF page for Salesforce1 tab like desktop lookup popup?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

A normal lookup is a text field in SF1 which turns into picklist if there are multiple entries with the entered characters . I want to show lookup just like salesforce desktop popup window to select the same in Salesforce1 .

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No.

You can not show lookup just like Desktop. Salesforce1 either don't support lookup and if it supports then in that case it show values as select list and allow you to search as well.